# An error with my javascript function, not sure what I'm doing wrong to calculate an stv equation

Tags: javascript, equation

All this suppose to do is to check 3 boxes for values, if 'v' or 's' is not empty for example, it will calculate 't', problem is it calculates 's' no matter which boxes I fill, it checks first if you've filled all textboxes (you're supposed to fill just two) if 'v' or 's' are not empty, it will check the next 'if' won't it?  it seems to randomly pick 'ifs' and also on some occasion return NaN as the answer.

Thanks ahead.

```
var count = 0;
function stv()
{
    var v = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Text1").value);
    var s = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Text2").value);
    var t = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Text3").value);

    if (v != "" && t != "" && s != "") {
        "Don't be stupid..."
        count++
    }
    if (v!="" && s!=""){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "time= " + s / v + "hours, or " + (s / v) * 60 + "minutes";
        count++;
    }
    if (s != "" && t != "") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "velocity= " + s / t + "kph";
        count++;
    }
    if (v != "" && t != "") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "displacement= " + (v * t) + "kilometers";
        count++;
    }

    if (count == 0){
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Fill in at least two parameters...";
}
    count = 0;
    document.getElementById("Text1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Text2").value = "";
    document.getElementById("Text3").value = "";
}
```

Comment: You're comparing the converted-to-numbers values with an empty string. You should compare the values of the inputs before calling `parseFloat` on them.

Comment: Added to the above comment, your other if's will execute even after your first if to check whether all 3 are filled in. Using `else if` will solve that for you.

Comment: Just use `if (v && s)` and so on. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/96mffgg4/

Comment: @ChrisG hopefully `0` is not a valid number

Comment: @epascarello It actually isn't, given that division by 0 is undefined, and calculating a speed for velocity or time being 0 makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you! I've solved it by not parsing at the beginning and placing an else after the first if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if checks are "failing" because parseFloat of "" is NaN and not equal to "". So you should be checking to see if it is not a number and not equal to an empty string.

```js
    var a = parseFloat("")
    if ( isNaN(a) ) console.log("I am not a number");    
    if ( a!="" ) console.log("I am not an empty string");
```